# SED no linux não funciona

Tags: sed

Boa tarde, estou com problemas para excluir uma linha no meu crontab utilizando o sed.

minha linha é esta:

```
0 1 * * * root shutdown -r +1
```

meu sed que não funciona:

```
sed '/0 1 * * * root shutdown -r +1/g' /etc/crontab  > /home/linaro/mycron
```

fiz um teste colocando uma palavra teste e criando um sed assim

```
sed '/teste/g' /home/linaro/mycron  > /home/linaro/mycron
```

e assim funcionou. Alguem pode me ajudar com isso?

Comment: Você não escapou os metacaracteres na expressão de busca

Comment: ficaria como ? o que é meta caractere

Answer (score 2):

Olá!

Creio que o Jefferson Quesado se referiu aos asteriscos. Ou seja, reescrevendo

`sed '/0 1 \* \* \* root shutdown -r +1/g' [arquivo-de-entrada] > [arquivo-de-saída]`

A barra invertida nesse caso indica que o metacaracter seguinte, que nada mais é do que um caracter com alguma propriedade distinta dos demais, deve ser interpretado como um normal. Mas também pode atribuir função alternativa para um caracter comum, como no caso de novas linhas, em geral representadas por `\n`.

Na maioria dos casos a metapropriedade do `*` faz com que sua comparação com qualquer caracter resulte em coincidência e, por isso, suponho que o resultado obtido tenha incluido todas as linhas e não apenas as esperadas.

Pela sua data de postagem, tomara que já tenha conseguido ao menos uma solução alternativa há tempos. Em todo caso, espero ajudar quem passar por aqui.